# writing user credentials too a file

Tags: java, authentication, server, file-handling

In eclipse I am building a very rudimentary server client application. It takes a user input and sends it too a text file called UsersData.txt located in the project directory, to later  use for authentication, I put the user input in an array list and try and pass it into the file but it does not write too the file and I am not too sure as too why.
this is the code for the client part of the application
https://gist.github.com/swordslinger/9abbff33bf76d77e4bc4e2779d1ad530/edit

```
package ie.gmit.sw;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server extends Thread {
    
    //variables for server
    private Socket conn;
    private int id;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    
    //variables for taking and sending info too console
    String option;
    String response;
    String message;
    
    //variables for users
    String storedUser="default";
    String storedPass="default";
    String regid = "default";
    String username;
    String password;
    
    //Arraylists for Users and Fleet
    ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
    ArrayList<Fleet> fleet = new ArrayList<Fleet>();
    
    //variables for fleet
     String storedName;
     String storedAge;
     String storedMachineId;
     String storedClubId;
     String storedVendor;
     String storedValuation;
     String storedLastSerKm;
     String storedLastSerDate;
     String storedNextSerKm;
     String storedCurKm;
     
     //variable for checking if user is valid
     boolean userExists = false;
    
    public Server(Socket c, int i, ArrayList<Users> user)
    {
        conn = c;
        id = i;
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        try 
        {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        
            
            //Server Conversation
            
            do
                {
                message = (String)in.readObject();
                
            
            out.writeObject("Press 1 for Login or 2 for Register");
            out.flush();
            
            option = (String)in.readObject();
            
            if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            {
                //read from user file too check credentials
                readUser();
                //Login
                out.writeObject("Please enter the userrname and password");
                out.flush();
                
                storedUser = (String)in.readObject();
                
                storedPass = (String)in.readObject();
                
                for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                    // if the credentials match, found = true
                    if (storedUser.equalsIgnoreCase(users.get(i).username)
                        && storedPass.equalsIgnoreCase(users.get(i).password)) {
                        userExists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    // else it is still false
                    else {
                        userExists = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        
            else if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
            {
                //Writes too file
                FileWriter fr = new FileWriter("UsersData.txt", true);
                BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter (fr);
                //Register
                out.writeObject("Please enter the username, password and ID");
                out.flush();
                
                storedUser = (String)in.readObject();
                storedPass = (String)in.readObject();
                regid = (String)in.readObject();
                
                //store users in array list
                Users newUsers = new Users(storedUser, storedPass);
                
                //output new user too file
                br.write("\n" + storedUser + " " + storedPass);
                users.add(newUsers);
                
                response ="OK";
                out.writeObject("OK");
                
                out.flush();
                //closeing buffer reader and file writer 
                br.close();
                fr.close();
                
            }
            
                }while(option.equalsIgnoreCase("2")|| response.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL"));
        
        //Logged in menu
        }
        
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            
        }
    }

    //read users from file
    private void readUser() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner s =  new Scanner(new File("UsersData.txt"));
        
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            users.add(new Users(s.next(), s.next()));
        }
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ServerSocket listener;
        Socket connection;
        int id=0;
        ArrayList<Users> users = null;
        
        try
        {
            listener = new ServerSocket(25000,10);
            
            while(true)
            {
                
                System.out.println("Listening for a connection");
                connection = listener.accept();
                System.out.println("Received Connection from "+connection.getInetAddress());
                
                Server th = new Server(connection,id, users);
                id++;
                th.start();
            }
        
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: I have never had anything but problems using ObjectStream's. Since this is a text-based protocol, I would use a BufferedReader/BufferedWriter.

Comment: so anywhere I have object streams just replace with with bufferedReader and bufferedWriter

Comment: You would have to use BufferedReader#readLine(), and you would have to make sure you have newlines after each string you write.

Comment: "he method readLine() is undefined for the type Server" as an error

Comment: Is Server a BufferedReader?

Comment: the Server is a thread

Comment: Please include the client part also. I think your repo is private. Not showing client code.

Comment: @seanskelton Then why are you using Server#readLine rather than BufferedReader#readLine()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“I am not too sure as to why”

You have an empty catch block, that is, when an error occurs, you ignore it. That is why you are unsure what the problem is.